# How to calculate the area of merged plane in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhEqr.png)

get the area of merged planes

I can get area of each plane, but planes overlapped with each other, I can get a area of them all, but it's not what I want, the overlapped areas should excluded.

```
var geom = plane.geometry;
var area = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < geom.faces.length; i++) {
    var face = geom.faces[i];
    var tri = new THREE.Triangle(geom.vertices[face.a], geom.vertices[face.b], geom.vertices[face.c]);
    var area = area + tri.getArea();
}
console.log(area);
```

There should be a method to calculate the area.
THREE.ShapeUtils.area( contour) gives a negative result.

Comment: [`ShapeUtils.area`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/ShapeUtils.area) Computes the area of a 2D contour polygon. See: [`ShapeBufferGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ShapeBufferGeometry)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight the edges of your geometry, you can use EdgesHelper:

```
var helper = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh, 0x00ffff );

helper.material.linewidth = 2;

scene.add( helper )
```

and get contour from Edges helper if required

Comment: Thank you. But the result is not right. Get contour from geometry is more accurate than from edges. I don't know why.